# How to change the order of the dimension of an image

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

I have a database of images with 5 bands :

`RGB + alpha (a) + topography (t).`

I know how to reverse RGB (without orther bands) to obtain BGR : `tf.reverse(image_patch, axis = [-1])`

with `image_patch` : `Tensor("Sub:0", shape=(256, 256, 5), dtype=float32)`

But how can I change the dimensions of this tensor, following this order : `BGRat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tf.reverse_sequence()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reverse_sequence) method.

**Sample code**

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Parameters
rows = 2
shift = 3

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=(rows, 5))
b = tf.reverse_sequence(a, seq_lengths=[shift] * rows, batch_dim = 0, seq_dim=1)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(b, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]}))
```

**Result**

```py
# a - sample input
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5]]

# b - shifted columns
[[3 2 1 4 5]
 [3 2 1 4 5]]
```